# Optimizing Postgres queries using Sequel gem

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I have a Ruby script using the Sequel gem to access my Postgres database.

At the moment, here are my calls:

```
@db[:items].insert_conflict.insert(:sku => sku, :name => itemName)
dbItem = Item.where(:sku => sku).first
dbPrice = Price.create(:price => foundPrice, :quantity => quantity, :status => status)
dbItem.add_price(dbPrice)
store.add_price(dbPrice)
```

Unfortunately, insert_conflict.insert returns either the key if it is inserted, and nil if it exists.. otherwise I'd be able to use the one call (to get the actual object that was inserted or already existed, see line 2). Is there any other way to reduce this to one call?

As for the last three calls, I believe since I'm adding relationships between three different schemas, there's no way to reduce this. But I'm including it just in case.

Comment: You want to insert new row if key combination (sku,name) does not exists and do nothing if it exists?

Comment: `Items` are keeping track of SKU numbers and product names. `Prices` are individual store pricing for those items. So I'm adding the item if it doesn't already exist, referencing that item as `dbItem`, and then adding the item reference to the price.